# How to import and run project, in Android Studio 1.1, from Github?

Tags: android, git, github

I want to checkout a project from github, run it on Android Studio 1.1, and be able to upload the code to github in a repo.

https://github.com/cam1911/MemoryMed
Here is the project I want to be able to edit, run, and push to a repo. The code is mine, but I ran into problems when I updated Android Studio today. It is not a Gradle project, it was originally made in Eclipse

I can't run the program, I keep getting "no module" in edit configuration. Can someone provide me an easy step by step tutorial on how to get code from github, edit in Android Studio 1.1, and push the changes to github?

Comment: Hi,i want to know if you solve this a problem ,i face the same and need help,please

Answer (score 1):

Unzip the github project to a folder. Open Android Studio. Go to File->Import Project. Then choose the specific project you want to import and then click Next->Finish. It will build the Gradle automatically and'll be ready for you to use.

P.S: In some versions of Android Studio a certain error occurs- error:package android.support.v4.app does not exist. To fix it go to Gradle Scripts->build.gradle(Module:app) and the add the dependecies:

```
dependencies {      
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'  
}
```

Then start an emulator and run your app

For more information: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to clone the gitHub project into your AndroidStudioProjects(workspace) folder using Git Bash and then keep on pushing it to the Github repository as and when you like.You can also use  GithubWindows https://windows.github.com/ for sync automatically.